# slf4j How to specify max logged number for a line

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I've got a huge number of log messages in project's log. I want to reduce that number by logging only first **N** of them for every line of code where log is used.

Are there any existent solutions for my task?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the debug level for filtering or log rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something i have tried myself, but if you use logback as the underlying logging mechanism of slf4j, I imagine you could write a custom filter that takes care of filtering the log output as you specify it.

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement a LoggerWrapper by myself.

We can obtain the current line of a caller, count its occurrence and decide whether print a message or not. I think it's quite simple but a kind of routine.